# How to use Symfony2 Validation Constraint Callback with validation groups to validate a single property

Tags: validation, symfony, callback

My Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;

/**
 * PriceQuoteRequest
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pricequote")
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"isGutterValid"}, groups={"flow_dormerRequest_step2"})
 */
class PriceQuoteRequest
{
    /**
     * @var integer $dormerInnerHeight
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="h", type="float")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"flow_dormerRequest_step2"})
     * @Assert\Range(min="80", max="1000", groups={"flow_dormerRequest_step2"})
     */
    public $dormerInnerHeight;

    /**
     * @var boolean $dormerGutter
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="gutter", type="boolean")
     *
     * @Assert\Type(type="boolean", groups={"flow_dormerRequest_step2"})
     * Assert\Callback(methods={"isGutterValid"}, groups={"flow_dormerRequest_step2"})
     */
    public $dormerGutter;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\AppBundle\Entity\GutterMaterial")
     *
     * Assert\Type(type="Acme\AppBundle\Entity\GutterMaterial", groups={"flow_dormerRequest_step2"})
     */
    public $dormerGutterMaterial;

    /**
     *
     * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
     *
     * Assert\Callback(groups={"flow_dormerRequest_step2"})
     */
    public function isGutterValid(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        if ($this->getDormerGutter() === true && $this->getDormerGutterMaterial() === null) {
            $context->buildViolation('Gutter checked but no Material selected.')
                ->atPath('dormerGutter')
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

My Test:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AppBundle\Tests\Entity;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

class RequestFunctionalTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager()
        ;
    }

    public function testDormerGutterValidator()
    {
        $priceQuoteRequest = new PriceQuoteRequest();

        $priceQuoteRequest->setDormerGutter(true);

        // Validating on single property will not call "isGutterValid" Callback, exptected only 1 error otherwise
        // $violationList = $this->getValidator()->validateProperty($priceQuoteRequest, 'dormerGutter', array('flow_dormerRequest_step2'));

        // Validating full object will call "isGutterValid" but return all errors resp. > 1
        $violationList = $this->getValidator()->validate($priceQuoteRequest, array('flow_dormerRequest_step2'));

        dump($violationList);

        $this->assertEquals(1, count($violationList));
    }
}
```

If **DormerGutter** is set to true (resp. checked in form) a **DormerGutterMaterial** has to be selected.

The *isGutterValid* method is supposed to check this and otherwise point the violation to the **DormerGutter** field:

```
if ($this->getDormerGutter() === true && $this->getDormerGutterMaterial() === null) {
    $context->buildViolation('Gutter checked but no Material selected.')
        ->atPath('dormerGutter')
        ->addViolation();
}
```

The Test sets the **DormerGutter** to true but selects no **DormerGutterMaterial**.
Validating on the property **DormerGutter** I expect to get that 1 error returned by the *isGutterValid* Callback.

Instead it will return 0 errors because calling *validateProperty* on a single property DOES NOT CALL the "global" Callback for the entire object resp. class.

Instead I can validate the complete object. This will indeed call the *isGutterValid* method.
It will return at least 2 errors since this also validates all the other properties e.g. **dormerInnerHeight**
Unfortunately - in my use case - I only want that 1 error returned.

**Is there a way to point a Callback to a single property only enabling me to call the validateProperty method and still fire the Callback?**

The alternative / workaround will of course be the usage of the Expression Constraint:

```
/**
 * @var boolean $dormerGutter
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="gutter", type="boolean")
 *
 * @Assert\Type(type="boolean", groups={"flow_dormerRequest_step2"})
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *  "this.getDormerGutterMaterial() !== null or this.getDormerGutter() == 0",
 *  message="Gutter checked but no Material selected.",
 *  groups={"flow_dormerRequest_step2"}
 * )
 */
public $dormerGutter;
```

Ps.: All validation groups are successfully linked to flow_dormerRequest_step2.

Full Code on GitHub Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/webdevilopers/7dbf2f072ab394e1311b)

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you to use an Entity validator.

For instance, in one project, I had a Vote entity which linked 2 users. (one in voter and one in votable->getTargetUser).

Here is Vote:

```
/**
 * Vote est l'entitĂŠ de jointure entre un juge, un jugĂŠ
 * et la votable choisie par le juge.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="vote")
 *     @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Face\Bundle\VoteBundle\Entity\Repository\VoteRepository")
 * @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 * @Assert\GroupSequence({"properties", "Vote"})
 * @AssertVote\UniqueCharacteristic
 * @AssertVote\VoterNotTargetUser
 */
class Vote
{

/**
 * Vote's id.
 *
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @Serializer\Expose
 */
private $id;

/**
 * User who gave the vote.
 *
 * @var User
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Face\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotNull(message = "vote.voter_user.not_null", groups={"properties"})
 * @Serializer\Expose
 */
private $voterUser;

/**
 * The votable (ie: profile) which the voterUser voted on.
 *
 * @var Votable
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(
 *  targetEntity="Face\Bundle\VoteBundle\Entity\AbstractVotable",
 *  inversedBy="votes",
 *  cascade={"persist"}
 * )
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotNull(message = "vote.votable.not_null", groups={"properties"})
 */
private $votable;
```

I had to make sur that my voter were different from the targetUser.

Then I created a new Constraint:

```
/**
 * Block votes of one User on its profile
 *
 * @package Face\Bundle\UserBundle\Validator\Validator
 */
class VoterNotTargetUserValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

    /**
     * The entity manager.
     *
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     *
     * @param EntityManager $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * Block votes of one User on its profile
     *
     * @param Vote       $value      The value that should be validated
     * @param Constraint $constraint The constraint for the validation
     *
     */
        public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
        {
        if ($value->getVoterUser() === $value->getVotable()->getTargetUser()) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message);
        }
    }
}
```

And the Validator used in Vote:

```
/**
 * Block votes of one User on its profile
 *
 * @package Face\Bundle\UserBundle\Validator\Validator
 */
class VoterNotTargetUserValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

    /**
     * The entity manager.
     *
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     *
     * @param EntityManager $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * Block votes of one User on its profile
     *
     * @param Vote       $value      The value that should be validated
     * @param Constraint $constraint The constraint for the validation
     *
     * @api
     */
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if ($value->getVoterUser() === $value->getVotable()->getTargetUser()) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see doc for further details like how to add it to the field you want to validate.

http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: Thanks @Grégory Elhaimer! I like the idea of creating a Custom Constraint as an alternative to the Symfony 2.6 Expression Constraint I mentioned. Unfortunately I think this will end up with the same problem when it comes to my Test class since the annotations append to the full class not a single element. You can only set the path for the error to the element. Will your Custom Constraint be called when I am running the validator method "validateProperty" only on that specific field or will I have to run the validation on the full class?

Comment: My bad, I read too fast :/. You'll have to run it on full class I guess. Since you need another property to validate another, you have to make sur that each property is valid. What you could is is mocking the whole object with valid data exept for dormerGutter. Then your validation will send you 1 error back.

Comment: Another smart approach by @bjo3rnf was to give the elements an extra validation group and then only use that group inside the Tests' "validate" method to reduce the number of expected errors. I've added an example on my gist for that workaround: https://gist.github.com/webdevilopers/7dbf2f072ab394e1311b